# elasticsearch search_analyzer is not applying filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot get search_analyzer to work as expected. I expect it to apply the specified analyzer to the inputed search string and then do the search.

I set the indexed analyzer to an **ngram tokenizer** with a l**owercase filter** and a **char replacement (- to _)**

I then want the search analyzer to **lowercase** and **replace (- to _)**.

Example document: {"filename": "AAA-BBB"}

Example search that should match: {"match": "AAA-b"}

Instead I have to search using: {"match": "aaa_b"}

elasticsearch version: 5.5

Mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "DO_tokenizer_ngram": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 30
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "DO_analyzer_ngram": {
                    "tokenizer": "DO_tokenizer_ngram",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "do_char_filter_dashes"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                },
                "DO_analyzer_search": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "do_char_filter_dashes"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "do_char_filter_dashes": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "(\\d+)-(?=\\d)",
                    "replacement": "$1_"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "images": {
            "properties": {
                "filename": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "DO_analyzer_ngram",
                    "search_analyzer": "DO_analyzer_search"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being an idiot. The search analyzer needed:

```
"tokenizer": "keyword"
```

instead of

```
"type": "keyword",
```