# Why is my elastic search prefix query case-sensitive despite using lowercase filters on both index and search?

Tags: elasticsearch

### The Problem

I am working on an autocompleter using ElasticSearch 6.2.3. I would like my query results (a list of pages with a Name field) to be ordered using the following priority:

1. Prefix match at start of "Name" (Prefix query)
2. Any other exact (whole word) match within "Name" (Term query)
3. Fuzzy match (this is currently done on a different field to Name using a ngram tokenizer ... so I assume cannot be relevant to my problem but I would like to apply this on the Name field as well)

### My Attempted Solution

I will be using a Bool/Should query consisting of three queries (corresponding to the three priorities above), using boost to define relative importance.

**The issue I am having is with the Prefix query - it appears to not be lowercasing the search query despite my search analyzer having the lowercase filter**. For example, the below query returns "Harry Potter" for 'harry' but returns zero results for 'Harry':

```
{ "query": { "prefix": { "Name.raw" : "Harry" } } }
```

I have verified using the `_analyze` API that both my analyzers do indeed lowercase the text "Harry" to "harry". Where am I going wrong?

From the ES documentation I understand I need to analyze the Name field in two different ways to enable use of both Prefix and Term queries:

1. using the "keyword" tokenizer to enable the [Prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) query (I have applied this on a `.raw` field)
2. using a standard analyzer to enable the [Term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) (I have applied this on the Name field)

I have checked duplicate questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105496/elasticsearch-search-analyzer-is-not-applying-filters) but the answers have not helped

My mapping and settings are below

ES Index Mapping

```
{
    "myIndex": {
        "mappings": {
            "pages": {
                "properties": {
                    "Id": {},
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "keywordAnalyzer",
                                "search_analyzer": "pageSearchAnalyzer"
                            }
                        },
                    "analyzer": "pageSearchAnalyzer"
                    },
                    "Tokens": {}, // Other fields not important for this question
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ES Index Settings

```
{
    "myIndex": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "ngram": {
                            "type": "edgeNGram",
                            "min_gram": "2",
                            "max_gram": "15"
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "keywordAnalyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "trim",
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "pageSearchAnalyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "trim",
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        },
                        "pageIndexAnalyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "trim",
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding",
                                "ngram"
                                ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "l2AXoENGRqafm42OSWWTAg",
                "version": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix queries don't analyze the search terms, so the text you pass into it bypasses whatever would be used as the search analyzer (in your case, the configured `search_analyzer: pageSearchAnalyzer`) and evaluates `Harry` as-is directly against the keyword-tokenized, custom-filtered `harry potter` that was the result of the `keywordAnalyzer` applied at index time.

In your case here, you'll need to do one of a few different things:

1. Since you're using a `lowercase` filter on the field, you could just always use lowercase terms in your prefix query (using application-side lowercasing if necessary)
2. Run a `match` query against an `edge_ngram`-analyzed field instead of a `prefix` query like described in the [ES search_analyzer docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html)

Here's an example of the latter:

**1) Create the index w/ ngram analyzer and (recommended) standard search analyzer**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "ngram": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": "2",
            "max_gram": "15"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "pageIndexAnalyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "trim",
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "ngram"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "pages": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "pageIndexAnalyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2) Index some sample docs**

```
POST my_index/pages/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Harry Potter"}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Hermione Granger"}
```

**3) Run the a match query against the ngram field**

```
POST my_index/pages/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "query": "Har",
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The recommendation from RustyBuckets is almost exactly what I was looking for. One modification was required: pageIndexAnalyzer should have the "keyword" tokenizer rather than "standard". Otherwise results like "When Sally Met Harry" appear sometimes above "Harry Potter and Elastic Search".

So my final approach has (a) "Name.prefixGram" which has  'keyword/edgeNGram' tokenizer and (b) "Name" which has 'standard/edgeNGram' tokenizer. (a) enables the prefix preference whilst (b) enables the usual autocompleter search .... not sure if this is how I am supposed to do it but it works

Comment: Ah - fair point, and I overshot your specific use case a bit RE: standard vs. keyword analyzed.  I'll update the example for the next passerby.

Comment: As for "not sure if this is how I am supposed to do it" - I think this is the canonical autocomplete implementation in Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html

There is a relatively new feature (added in 5.0, revamped in 6.0) called "Suggesters" that may be of interests, but is a slight workflow departure: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use `match_phrase_prefix` query without using `.keyword` suffix. Check the docs at here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html